# c# locking a file to not be used by external processes (reading)

Tags: c#

How can I lock a specific file to not be used (read) by other programs?
I tried by simply reading the file using c# but I still can read the file.

Using the code below:

```
    using (var sys = new FileStream(@"path", FileMode.Open))
    {
        while (true)
        {

        }
    }
```

I can only prevent appending or editing the file.
Is there any way to prevent **reading the file** by any other external processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by adding the `FileShare.None` parameter like

```
var sys = new FileStream(@"path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```